# Removing duplicates and summing columns in arrays?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an Excel pivot table with a number of columns, 3 of which I want to summarise, and then via VBA place in a table on a word document.

The data in the pivot is structure similar to that in the table below, with a number of other columns off to the left.

| Material | Item Num | Qty Reqd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Oil | 123 | 1 |
| Bolt | 987 | 4 |
| (blank) | (blank) | (blank) |
| Oil | 123 | 9 |
| (blank) | (blank) | (blank) |
| Bolt | 321 | 8 |
| Oil | 123 | 4 |
| (blank) | (blank) | (blank) |

I would like to eliminate the duplicates using the 'Item Num' as the key field as that will always be unique.  I would then like to sum the Qty Reqd so the table in word looks as below.

| Material | Item Num | Qty Reqd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Oil | 123 | 14 |
| Bolt | 987 | 4 |
| Bolt | 321 | 8 |

I've not really had much success in doing this.  I've just been doing it manually after the word document is written.

The code I'm currently using to grab the 3 columns and place them in an array is below.

```
Material = Item.Offset(0, 4).Text
If Material <> "(blank)" Then
  MaterialList(UBound(MaterialList)) = Material
  ItemList(UBound(ItemList)) = Item.Offset(0, 5).Text
  QtyList(UBound(QtyList)) = Item.Offset(0, 6).Text
  ReDim Preserve MaterialList(UBound(MaterialList) + 1)
  ReDim Preserve ItemList(UBound(ItemList) + 1)                                                                        
  ReDim Preserve QtyList(UBound(QtyList) + 1)
End If
```

Then when it comes time to write it to the Word Document table I've been using the below code.

```
' If Material exists, go to the Word BM and place the quick part Material Table in the doc
If UBound(MaterialList) > 0 Then 
  objDoc.Bookmarks("Material_Table").Select
  objWord.Templates(TemplateName). _
  BuildingBlockEntries("Material_Table").Insert _
  Where:=objWord.Selection.Range, _
  RichText:=True
  objDoc.Bookmarks("Material").Select

' Count how many table rows to add                                              
If UBound(MaterialList) > 1 Then objWord.Selection.InsertRowsBelow (UBound(MaterialList) - 1)
objDoc.Bookmarks("Material").Select

' Then place the data in the table cells
For Each Item In MaterialList 
  If Item <> "" Then
     objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=Item
     objWord.Selection.MoveDown
  End If
Next Item
                                              
objDoc.Bookmarks("Stk").Select
For Each Item In ItemList
   objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=Item
   objWord.Selection.MoveDown
Next Item

objDoc.Bookmarks("Qty").Select
For Each Item In QtyList
   objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=Item
   objWord.Selection.MoveDown
Next Item

Else ' get rid of the BM
   objDoc.Bookmarks("Material_Table").Select
   objWord.Selection.Delete
End If
```

But this obviously doesn't remove the duplicates or sum the qty.  I'm left to do that after document creation is finished.

I have looked at using the code below to remove the duplicates and that seems to work.  I just can't figure out how to maintain the connection between material, item and qty, and at the same time sum the qty.

```
Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = LBound(MaterialList) To UBound(MaterialList)
   oDict(MaterialList(i)) = True
Next
MaterialList = oDict.Keys()
```

All help much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you create an output in Excel based on the **source data** of your pivot table that sums the unique values. No need to do this in VBA. And then place this table into the Word doc

Comment: Hi Ike, I have a lot more info in the pivot that gets used in other tables.  The pivot get filtered so not all info from the source data gets used.  It is also important that information around material remains related to this other information so creating custom pivots or going direct to the source data is not an option.

Comment: Pivot table is not affected ... Instead you will have _two_ outputs: 1) raw data --> pivot; 2) raw data --> summary table --> output to Word. You could create the second output on the fly and delete it after adding it to Word.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code. It uses a dictionary for obtaining unique keys and their sum. Then place the dictionary data in a final array (`arrFin`), followed by opening a new Word session, open a new document, insert a table and populate it with the above array content:

```
Sub ExtractUniquePlaceInWordTable()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin
  Dim i As Long, k As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  
  arr = ws.Range("A1:C" & lastR).Value2
  
  'load the dictionary with unique summarized data:
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 
  For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 1) <> "" And arr(i, 1) <> "(blank)" Then
        dict(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)) = _
           dict(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)) + arr(i, 3)
    End If
  Next i
  
  'Populate final arr:
  ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count + 1, 1 To 3)
  'load the header:
  For i = 1 To 3: arrFin(1, i) = arr(1, i): Next i
  k = 1
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    k = k + 1
    arrFin(k, 1) = Split(dict.keys()(i), "|")(0)
    arrFin(k, 2) = Split(dict.keys()(i), "|")(1)
    arrFin(k, 3) = dict.Items()(i)
  Next i
  
  'open a new Word session, open a new document, insert a table and populate it with the array content
  Dim objWord, doc As Object, tbl As Object
  Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  With objWord
    .Visible = True
    Set doc = .Documents.Add
    With doc
        Set tbl = .tables.Add(Range:=.Range(0, 0), NumRows:=UBound(arrFin), NumColumns:=UBound(arrFin, 2))
        With tbl
            .Borders.InsideLineStyle = 1 '[wdLineStyleSingle
            .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = 7 'wdLineStyleDouble
            .rows.SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=-37, RulerStyle:=0 'wdAdjustNone
            'fill the table from the array:
            For i = 1 To UBound(arrFin)
                For k = 1 To UBound(arrFin, 2)
                    .cell(i, k).Range.text = arrFin(i, k)
                Next k
            Next i
        End With
    End With
  End With
  
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, I do not understand this part `dict(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)) = _
           dict(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)) + arr(i, 3)`

Comment: @Soma What do you mean? `arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)` it's a simple concatenation between the first two array columns, separated by "|".  `dict(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2))` creates **UNIQUE** keys for the respective columns combination. And the whole code line summarizes the values of the third column for the first two columns unique combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying data from the wrong pivot table.

Make a new pivot table in a new tab/sheet that doesn't have those extra columns and you'll have the results deduplicated and aggregated for you.

If you have control of the workbook design, just add it into a new sheet (and consider hiding the sheet).

If you don't then you'll have to build the pivot table in memory (i.e. a workbook you create and discard without saving). To code this, "cheat" by recordimg a macro of creating a new workbook, creating that pivot table based on the data or the pivot table you were originally using, and closing the workbook without saving once you're done with it. This macro won't be exactly the code you want but it will give you a huge headstart.

Comment: Thanks, however, It is important that information around material remains related to this other information in the pivot so creating another pivot will break that connection unfortunately.

Comment: Wait... are you telling me that you can't have two separate pivot tables because they interfere with each other? If so, I've never heard of that and would love to know more.